# MySQL A transaction id in a record of table is newer than the system-wide maximum

Tags: mysql, innodb

I got this issue when working with mysql. Yesterday I cannot query the new records of table anymore (can query old record of previous days). Also, I cannot dump the backup data. When I get the log of MySQL, it show like that

```
022-08-18T08:10:18.911945Z 11 [Warning] [MY-013021] [InnoDB] A transaction id in a record of table `timesheet`.`app_timesheet_entries` is newer than the system-wide maximum.
2022-08-18T08:10:18.911965Z 11 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: buf0buf.cc:3224:block->page.get_space() != nullptr thread 139904938870528
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
08:10:18 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7f3da4000fc0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f3e282efd10 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x5625d5ef94c1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x2fb) [0x5625d4d98fbb]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_server_abort()+0x76) [0x5625d4d99106]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_abort()+0xe) [0x5625d5ef34be]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0x349) [0x5625d6183f59]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x25b4e28) [0x5625d61eae28]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(buf_page_init_for_read(dberr_t*, unsigned long, page_id_t const&, page_size_t const&, bool)+0x2b9) [0x5625d61f6059]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(buf_read_page_low(dberr_t*, bool, unsigned long, unsigned long, page_id_t const&, page_size_t const&, bool)+0x9e) [0x5625d622f19e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(buf_read_page(page_id_t const&, page_size_t const&)+0x4a) [0x5625d622f8ea]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Buf_fetch<Buf_fetch_normal>::read_page()+0x38) [0x5625d61eb4d8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Buf_fetch_normal::get(buf_block_t*&)+0x657) [0x5625d61f7017]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Buf_fetch<Buf_fetch_normal>::single_page()+0x59) [0x5625d61f7109]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(buf_page_get_gen(page_id_t const&, page_size_t const&, unsigned long, buf_block_t*, Page_fetch, ut::Location, mtr_t*, bool)+0x233) [0x5625d61f8713]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x251c049) [0x5625d6152049]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(trx_undo_prev_version_build(unsigned char const*, mtr_t*, unsigned char const*, dict_index_t const*, unsigned long*, mem_block_info_t*, unsigned char**, mem_block_info_t*, dtuple_t const**, unsigned long, lob::undo_vers_t*)+0x698) [0x5625d6152908]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(row_vers_build_for_consistent_read(unsigned char const*, mtr_t*, dict_index_t*, unsigned long**, ReadView*, mem_block_info_t**, mem_block_info_t*, unsigned char**, dtuple_t const**, lob::undo_vers_t*)+0x2ac) [0x5625d61036fc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(row_search_mvcc(unsigned char*, page_cur_mode_t, row_prebuilt_t*, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x2def) [0x5625d60eadaf]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::general_fetch(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x1f8) [0x5625d5f55a88]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_index_next(unsigned char*)+0x25d) [0x5625d4eb43fd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(IndexScanIterator<false>::Read()+0x55) [0x5625d5000b15]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(FilterIterator::Read()+0x18) [0x5625d516e5d8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Query_expression::ExecuteIteratorQuery(THD*)+0x376) [0x5625d4d021e6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Query_expression::execute(THD*)+0x33) [0x5625d4d02493]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x186) [0x5625d4c8f8d6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0xa00) [0x5625d4c2bc30]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_sql_command(THD*, Parser_state*)+0x434) [0x5625d4c30a94]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x1d17) [0x5625d4c32cd7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x207) [0x5625d4c33fd7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1153e48) [0x5625d4d89e48]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x282ea4d) [0x5625d6464a4d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8609) [0x7f3e4333d609]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f3e425a9163]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f3da421f720): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 11
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

I'm appricate any help to let me know what is the root cause of it
Thanks

Comment: Could post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table> ` structure

Comment: Cannot run this command and command: check table xyz. It break the connection and show mysql has gone away. For other tables, it can run

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: Did you try to copy a tablespace file from another MySQL instance? Probably `timesheet/app_timesheet_entries.ibd` but perhaps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error log in mysql8(version 8.0.30), Mysql keep crashing . So we set force_recovery=6 and export data of broken table (as many as we could) to a csv file,then drop table and create it and import data. After that Mysql is working fine till now.